# disabling autocomplete for admin-on-rest SimpleForm

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

Is there a possibility to disable autocomplete for AOR SimpleForm component?
I tried various combinations of the following:

```
<SimpleForm autoComplete="off">
```

But nothing seems to work.
Can it be customized in such a manner or does it require creating your own component?
I need it specifically for AOR (not react-admin).
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might struggle with the basic understanding on how to disable auto complete, so here's a catch up:

## How does disabling auto complete work in HTML?

[`autocomplete`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) is a `HTML attribute`for `input` elements. Possible values are `on` and `off`.

You can disable autocomplete by using it like this:

`<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">`

## How can I apply this to React?

> React has always provided a JavaScript-centric API to the DOM. Since React components often take both custom and DOM-related props, React uses the camelCase convention just like the DOM APIs

[Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

The conclusion is, you have to set the **property** `autoComplete` to `off` on those **components aka input fields**, not on the from element around the input fields.

### Example

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input name="email" autoComplete='off' />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

In your case, the components is propably called `TextInput`.

[After looking at the source](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/c15559c266d449ffc4e39563971822f2f9563bf7/src/mui/input/TextInput.js), I've found out that AOR uses [`TextField`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/8b5cd6af2adebd4909b5ba06f5d82a86549a3520/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js#L180) of `material-ui`, which accepts `autoComplete` as property.

So if you either pass `input={{ autoComplete: 'off' }}` or `options={{ autoComplete: 'off' }}` you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried this as well before posting my answer. Unfortunately it did not help. I guess one has to override admin-on-rest components to achieve this effect.

Comment: @AlgorithmFromHell Can you try `<TextInput options={{ autoComplete: 'off' }} />`?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the `options` bit. Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**No. This is not possible on Chrome**

Previously you can set `autoComplete="off"`, but now it's not possible because Google Chrome now allow you to control it anymore.